# Can I trust project-hosting websites after Sourceforge?

Tags: project-hosting

Sourceforge was once the number one in project hosting for open source projects. But things have changed. And [some things](http://blog.gluster.org/2013/08/how-far-the-once-mighty-sourceforge-has-fallen/) Sourceforge does are worrying. The adware injected into binaries of Open-Source-projects is indeed not worthy of an OSS-hoster.

Now github or Google Code seem like good alternatives. The question I ask myself is: can I trust these sites, that down the line they not may resort to similar measures to squeeze money out of the users?

Comment: Google Code is closing, btw: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/03/google-to-close-google-code-open-source-project-hosting/. And as someone who was involved in the recent news around SF's behavior, I can tell that trusting code/project hosting sites, at least in the long run, is something I probably will never be able to do again. But I think that this question is a bit too opinion-based for SE.

Comment: Just so you know, Google Code is going away...

Comment: Think this question is too opinion-based, (slant website is better for that) - http://www.slant.co/topics/2483/~what-are-the-best-alternatives-to-sourceforge

Answer (score 4):

Your trust level of any service is up to you. Do you trust GitHub? Do you trust your ISP? Do you trust your own machine?

If you do not trust GitHub, where do you host your code? An alternative like BitBucket? Do you trust them? Your own private server? Do you trust the company you rented the server from? It never ends.

GitHub appears to be a pretty good choice, they don't appear to be doing much evil in the form of user mistrust (although there was a bit of drama with regards to claims of sexual harassment within the company).

Comment: The point is - Sourceforge seemed trustworthy back then. Things change.

Comment: @Mnementh Trust isn't a one time question. It's one you ask yourself continually. When a service loses your trust to a certain level, you leave it.

Answer (score 0):

You can (could, for Google Code) trust these sites, although that's primarily based on a user's experience with these sites.

As far as GitHub goes, they don't try to *squeeze* money out of you... Git/GitHub is an elaborate system that's great for open source hosting, managing, collaberation, and also contributing to other's code.  GitHub also provides a community, in which you basically get free promotion (if your project is interesting enough to the community).

But in the case that you need a private repository (proprietary project hosting) is when they'll charge month, based on the amount of repositories you want.

([You can see their price table here](https://github.com/pricing) for their private hosting, although that really goes against the terms of open source...  Just some extra information).

As far as Google Code goes, [they're officially shutting down](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html), so you should no longer use them.